# Typescript typedoc documenting export * as {component} from "file"

Tags: javascript, typescript, typedoc

I have a ts file with exports and when using typedoc to generate documentation it is going over it I get the following error

```
Error: /builds/npm-modules/cas_three_card_poker/node_modules/@firefly/cas_common_lib/lib/cas_common_lib.d.ts(269)
 'from' expected.
```

each of these files exports are just exporting a function with the same name INIT `export { INIT };`

it doesn't like the `export * as someName from 'fileName'` If I switch it to `export { INIT as someName } from 'fileName'` it passes typedoc but the export actually fails in typescript so I can't use this.

Does anyone know how I can get the `export * as` working wth typedoc. I would like to avoid changing the file that is exporting because these are auto generated through a third party tool.

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of TypeScript. That error's coming from TypeScript when TypeDoc calls it, not from TypeDoc itself.

Comment: Thankyou @gerrit0, I think typedoc might be using the incorrect typescript version and not the same one im using cheers!